# existence of a non measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am currently trying to understand a proof that is supposed to help proving the existence on non measurable sets
the proof consists of showing that the following function that I will define cannot exist.

- $\lambda : \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R_+} \cup\{+\infty\} $

$\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set containing all the real subsets

- this function has to be an extension of the idea of length so $\lambda(\text{any interval})$ should equal the length of that interval (right endpoint $-$ left endpoint)
- $\forall A \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}), \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \;\;\; \lambda(A) = \lambda(\{y+x \; \text{such that} y \in A\})$
- finally it has to be $\sigma$-additive

now to prove that we use the classical reductio ad absurdum by assuming that such a function actually exists and then we try to find a way to stumble on a contradiction

and here comes the part where I'm stuck :

first let me introduce an equivalence relation '$*$' that I don't see how it can be of any kind of help but it apparently is very crucial to achieve the proof

- $x,\;y\;\in \mathbb{R}\;\;\;x*y \iff y-x \in \mathbb{Q}$

now in the sources I'm using they claim that the quotient space $\Omega$ (a.k.a. set of all the classes) is clearly not countable because if we assume that it was indeed countable then since all the equivalent classes $[x]$ are countable (1st thing I want to understand.. I can't think of an equivalence set that's not countable but I don't get it why they are countable... please explain) then $\mathbb{R}$ would be countable because any point of $\mathbb{R}$ can be represented by an element of $\Omega$ and an element of $[x]$... contradiction (and here I'm completely lost... please shed some light on this. thank you !)

Comment: It is not clear one thing: *"(1st thing I want to understand.. I can't think of an equivalence set that's not countable but I don't get it why they are countable... please explain)"*. Do you mean that you **can** think of an equivalence set that is uncountable but you have problems with this one?

Comment: no I meant that I don't understand why the equivalent classes are  countable

also every single class I think of for example [0] its class is basically $\mathbb{Q}$ which is countable and let's say for a random real number $a$ $[a]$ is I think $\mathbb{Q-a}$ which is also countable but I feel like my reasoning is whacky and false

Answer (score 2):

Why make equivalence classes- you're trying to make a weird(=non-measurable) set, and equivalence classes are subsets.

Why countable - the equivalence class $[0]$ is $\mathbb Q$ in disguise, and all other classes are translates of this by an element in $\mathbb Q^c$.

The decomposition is purely because you have an equivalence relation, which partitions the space. Consider the simpler example $\mathbb Z$ and $x*y$ iff $x-y=2k $ for some $k$. Clearly the classes are $2\mathbb Z$ and $2\mathbb Z+1$ and the quotient space $\mathbb Z /[0]=\mathbb Z /2\mathbb Z$, telling me which equivalence class $[x]$ it is telling me odd or even and giving me an element of $[x]$ is like giving me the $k$.